# Midfile between Logic Pro X and OnSong

Tags: midi, export

I am exporting a midi file from Logic Pro X. 
In Logic it is 3.48 minutes long at 117bpm
When I import it into OnSong it is interpreted as 7:12 minutes long
if I take the same midi file and add it to Ableton Live it 3:48.
I have tried quantisation, changing to events which I read at Apple support
The file contains a Program Change for each bar.
And I have added a muted C3 note for each bar as well just to see if it made any difference. 
I use the midi file to control stage light. Each program change is a new scene.
So not have the correct length makes it pretty unusable. I am am out of ideas.

Comment: I'd speak to the makers of OnSong - a midi file is an old, well-established format & Logic is certainly capable of saving one with all the correct flags; meaning OnSong [which I don't know at all] is potentially misinterpreting something. That Ableton can import it correctly would reinforce that possibility.

Comment: Thx, I have rased the question at OnSong support, but no reply so far.